# How I can have the command line on bash or zsh always in the same place?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, zsh, iterm

Okay, this maybe sounds wear.

When I use the terminal after every command I have to search where the input of my terminal is because it goes down with the stream.

How I can have a fixed position for my input?

Comment: Would it be an option to have the input always at the bottom line of the terminal? As such you could just output a screen full of empty lines when you first start your shell session: `for i in $(seq $LINES) ; do echo  ; done `

Comment: oh, I prefer on the top but thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not guaranteed to work, but will with some terminals/emulators in bash:

```
PS1='\[\033[1;0H\]\s-\v\$ '
```

This will always put the prompt at the top line. You probably want the cursor at the bottom, though so you can try:

```
PS1='\[\033[$LINES;0H\]\s-\v\$ '
```

or more simply:

```
PS1='\[\033[1000;0H\]\s-\v\$ '
```

Comment: Okay! One more step, but I still want to be able to scroll.

Comment: What do you mean?  You can pipe data to a pager (eg `less`) and scroll to your hearts content.